# Which machine learning should I choose for a one->list relation

Tags: machine-learning, computation-models

I'm trying to write machine learning software that will predict a list of 3 values from a given number input (reverse grayscale). There is a function determining values of the list to the grayscale, but finding the inverse by hand seems impossible. I think something like Markov Chains or a random forest algorithm might be useful but I wanted to know if there were any others/better ones?